# listagg in SQL to group rows in to one row

Tags: sql, oracle11g, listagg

i have a table 1 shown below

```
Name  role       F1     status1 status 2 
sam   player     yes      null   null
sam   admin      yes     null    null
sam   guest       no      x       x
```

i want the result to be

```
Name  role         status1 status 2 
  sam admin,player    x       x
```

i have done a query to list_agg the role in to one row.but the status is null for sam to show when F1='yes'

query i used

```
 select name,list_agg(role,',') within group(order by name),max(status1),max(status2)
from table 1 where F1='yes'
group by name
```

but i get something like this

```
name role          status1   status2 
sam  admin,player     null      null
```

i want the where to work only on role column and the max(status1) to be in status1 i.e.'x'.please help me .thank you

Comment: Is there something you are not telling us? I would be very surprised if you didn't get an error message when executing your query. You are grouping by name, but try to show unaggregated fields, such as `water-access` rather than `min(water-access)` or `max(water-access)` or the like.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner.sry i have update the question.please help me

Comment: Use Tim's query. Replace `LISTAGG(Role, ',')` with `LISTAGG(CASE WHEN F1 = 'yes' THEN Role END, ',')` so as to only add roles to the string when F1 is yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using `LISTAGG()` within a `GROUP BY` query:

```
SELECT Name,
    LISTAGG(Role, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Role) "Role"
    MAX(CASE WHEN water_access = 'Y' THEN 'Y' ELSE NULL END) "water_access",
    MAX(CASE WHEN food_access = 'Y'  THEN 'Y' ELSE NULL END) "food_access",
    MAX(CASE WHEN power_access = 'Y' THEN 'Y' ELSE NULL END) "power_access"
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY Name
ORDER BY Name DESC
```

Note that I chose to order the aggregation of each `Name` group using the `Role`, because you didn't provide us with any column which could give the ordering you show in your expected output.

Second note: `MAX()` in Oracle ignores `NULL` values, so it can be used in the pivot to correctly identify the `Y` values you want to appear.

Answer (score 1):

try this out...

```
 select * from table_name pivot(sum(name) for role
```